# How to upload a file to amazon s3 through angular 5?

Tags: angular, amazon-s3, angular5, angular2-services, knox-amazon-s3-client

i'm just trying to upload a file to amazon s3  in angular 5 app but ,i did't find any way for it .Any help on this issue?

Comment: You may add some code that you have tried and not ask for a direct answer to this question. Request for close.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Fine Uploader library to upload an image on Amazon S3.

Please visit below link for more info and tutorial.

-> https://docs.fineuploader.com/features/modules.html

**Npm Package:**

-> https://www.npmjs.com/package/fine-uploader